# foreach array from json in php

Tags: php, json

I need to get a json_decode file to an array with foreach.

JSON_decode:

```
array(4) { ["success"]=> bool(true) ["lowest_price"]=> string(7) "0,76€" ["volume"]=> string(2) "94" ["median_price"]=> string(7) "0,81€" }
```

My current Code:

```
foreach($json_decode as $price) {

        $test = $price['lowest_price']; 
}
```

Output:

```
var_dump($test); // string(1) "0"
```

It only output the first char of my array ['lowest_price']

Why it dont output this?:

```
0,76€
```

Maybe you can help me.
Thanks!

Comment: the value of success is a boolean, so it will output `true`, `false`, `1` or `0`. So why should it output `Success`?

Comment: @MuhammadSumonMollaSelim I'm an idiot :D:D you are so right, but when i now will get the  ["lowest_price"], it output the first char of this string. Do you know a solution?

Comment: how are you trying it?

Comment: @MuhammadSumonMollaSelim i updated my question ^^

Comment: where you have placed the `var_dump()` in your code?

Comment: @MuhammadSumonMollaSelim i return this from a function

Comment: are you trying var_dump() within the loop?

Comment: @MuhammadSumonMollaSelim No, i return the var_dump() as standalone on the end of my function

Comment: try within the loop. outside of the loop, it will give you the last value from the array.

Comment: @MuhammadSumonMollaSelim inside the loop, it gives me back "NULL"

Comment: what does $json_decode['lowest_price'] shows?

Comment: @MuhammadSumonMollaSelim ahh, this is working for me. this will show the complete string

Comment: as your $json_decode is returning a single array, you don't need to loop through it. just print the value.

Comment: @MuhammadSumonMollaSelim Thanks!

Comment: if my answer helped you, please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

The value of `success` is a boolean, so it will output true, false, 1 or 0. Not `Success`.

EDIT: As your `$json_decode` is returning a single array, no need to use `foreach` loop. Instead use it as an array, get the value simple like this:

`echo $json_decode['lowest_price'];`

Comment: yeah, i gave you a answer in my comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37997242/foreach-array-from-json-in-php?noredirect=1#comment63438768_37997242

Answer (score 0):

you get object you need get array after `json_decode`

```
foreach(json_decode($array,true) as $arr) {

}
```

Comment: yeah, but this is exactly what iam doing, or?